# Is there any Tamil virtual keyboard for react web application?

Tags: reactjs, keyboard, virtual-keyboard, on-screen-keyboard, tamil

Is there any Tamil virtual keyboard for react web application, I tried simple-Keyboard and virtual-keyboard package but can't find Tamil language in it.
Any suggestion for Tamil virtual keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this 'cosmic-tamil-keyboard' npm package virtual keyboard for Tamil language alone it worked for me.

npm package URL: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cosmic-tamil-keyboard

> [image: Tamil virtual keyboard]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try it out and let you know.